# What is the function of setDefaultEncoding in ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, utf-8, character-encoding, properties-file

AFAIK, Spring's `ResourceBundleMessageSource` builds on the standard J2SE `java.util.ResourceBundle` and `java.util.Properties`, which are not able to handle file encodings other than ISO-8859-1.
But in many sample code I see this:

```java
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
resource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
```

What is the function of the line `resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");`? It makes me confused, can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Properties are loaded as follows in [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html):

```
this.propertiesPersister.load(props, new InputStreamReader(is, encoding));
```

Look at the [spring-context source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.java#L588). In the further course the file is read via the `java.util.Properties` [`public void load(Reader reader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-) method, which takes the encoding-aware `InputStreamReader(is, encoding)`, as an argument.

That means that also regular `java.util.Properties` can be loaded with a different encoding.

**Example**

PropertyReader.java

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class PropertyReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        List<String> locales = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("en", "ru", "de"));
        for (String loc : locales) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(loc);
            String value = context.getMessage("example", null, locale);
            System.out.println(value);
        }
        ((AbstractApplicationContext) context).close();
    }
}
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>messages</value>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding">
            <value>UTF-8</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

messages.properties

```
example=Example
```

messages_de.properties

```
example=Beispiel
```

messages_ru.properties

```
example=образец
```

**Result without defaultEncoding**

Comment the property in context.xml

```
Example
Ð¾Ð±ÑÐ°Ð·ÐµÑ
Beispiel
```

**Result with defaultEncoding**

```
Example
образец
Beispiel
```

Same result for the programmatic approach.

Comment: But when I setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8"), the properties file contains utf-8 characters, the result shows question mark for those utf-8 characters

Comment: Just updated my answer with a little example, if you would like to test it yourself.